# My CodeIgniter controller when passed with id as argument just taking one specific id all the time?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

my userlisting provides link to edit users and update profile as when one clicks the screen name of the user then it goes to profile update view with the id of corresponding user:

```
    //url:
    localhost/damcombd/admin/userprofile/userupdate/3
```

The form loads nice and address bar and on mouse over status bar both shows the link as above
but in reality in the controller if i pull something with this id say from user model it just goes to the first record or the id 1.. and doing it all the way.. try as i might!

What could be the reason? Checked for any hardcoded ids too.. but that's not the case..

```
    //with this one too I create a row and get it back  like:
    $this->commonmodel->create_and_get($table,$data){
      $this->db->insert($table,$data);
      $lastid=$this->db->insert_id();
      $getback=$this->db->get($table,array('id'=>$lastid))->result_array();
      return $getback[0];
```

But what it return every time the first row.. I dont know like the userprofile updating above this one also shitting around.. Is it a bug or something..I dont get it at all..try as I might:( :( Please do something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second problem I mentioned is solved when I used

```
   $this->db->get_where($table,array('id'=>$lastid));
   //actually for get the above line would have been false syntax..
```

I think I will I figure next one out too...

My First problem is solved too... That exact way actually..
to describe it a bit so that some one might be helped..

```
    //If u use
    $obj=$this->db->get($table,array('id'=>$lastid))->result_array(); //here then
    // it will actually do a simple get all operation and returning:
    return $obj[0] //will obviously return the very first row..try as u might.
    //so for querying with id always use:
    $this->db->get_where();
```

Comment: I think you may use ->row_array() instead of ->result_array() to get only the first row. Just in case you didn't do it, read the manual with this for Selects http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select and more important, for fetching results: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

This may be because:

a) In your routes you're specifying an id it's taking all the time:

b) Your controller is taking a wrong id

c) Your model is executing a wrong query.

What I'd do: Check you have in the routes applocation/config/routes a sentence with

```
    $routes['admin/userprofile/userupdate/(:num)'] = 'admin/userprofile/userupdate/$1'
```

Maybe you forgot the $ before the 1, ;P.

Then, check the value you're sending, for being sure is the right id, after receiving the POST/GET value, print it and check if this value is the expected one (you're editing user 2, so you get id 2 and so on).

If the value is correct, check what are you retrieving from the database. In your model, you can write:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

and check what SQL query is executing. Just do as I wrote you above, and tell us what happens, :D

Comment: No brother, my routes are not configured for userprofile.. Well I think it might be some subtle gotcha somewhere or a bug.. Could u please tell any more?